# How to find and replace "." with NA in price data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file with daily price values listed by date. For some of the price values excel has no numerical data but a . instead (I believe this means that no price data were recorded for those dates. This file was imported to R and the price values that had a "." in Excel also have a "." in R.

I would like to replace "." with `NA` but the methods I have applied are not working.

I've tried to mutate the price vector and to replace the values in the price vector to `NA`.

Here are some of the steps I've tried:

Step 1:

```
btc %>% mutate(btc = if_else(BCUD == ".", NA))
```

Step 2:

```
replace(btc$BCUD, " ", NA)
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `if_else`. It takes 3 arguments: a predicate that evaluates to true or false, a value for if it's true, and a value for if it's false. You've given it 2 arguments.

Comment: Do you read in the data using `read.csv()`? Try giving it the argument `na.strings = c("NA", ".")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can replace "."  with NA:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- tibble(x = c("a", ".", "b"))
mydata 
# A tibble: 3 x 1
      x
  <chr>
1     a
2     .
3     b
```

The second row contains ".". Here is how you get rid of it:

```
mydata %>% mutate(x = if_else(x == ".", NA_character_, x))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
      x
  <chr>
1     a
2  <NA>
3     b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to replace "." with NA for a single variable

```
  btc$BCUD[btc$BCUD == "."] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this and it was a success. Much appreciated!!!